# How can I pass higher order functions via ocpu.rpc?

Tags: r, macros, package, opencpu

I'm trying to pass a function to a function in my [opencpu](https://www.opencpu.org/) app using `ocpu.rpc`. I know the `opencpu` API can handle it because I've tested with the `sapply` function in base `R` (among others) using the [API test facility](http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/test/).

[image: opencpu accepts functions as arguments]

However, I've been unable to accomplish the same thing from `ocpu.rpc`. I just see `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

```
ocpu.rpc("sapply", 
  {FUN: "sqrt", X: [1,4,9,16,25,36]}, 
  function(output) { output } })
```

Can anyone provide an example as to how to make this call (and return the JSON vector) using `ocpu.rpc`?

I'd ask that you would help me create a `jsfiddle` for it, but recently I have been unable to edit fiddles.

[image: jquery or opencpu has been blocked]

Comment: This jsfiddle editing issue seems to be happening intermittently wherever I am. I'm wondering if they just don't preserve javascript library load order and it works half the time by chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can use `match.fun` to turn the `JSON` argument into a function expression on R's side. This is actually what `sapply` does by default. I just had the return value wrong. I was basing my code off of the `lowess` example, which returns a list with 2 arguments: `x` and `y`.

```
//set CORS to call "stocks" package on public server
ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R")

//some example data
var mydata = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];

//call R function: stats::var(x=data)
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
    var req = ocpu.rpc("sapply",{
        X : mydata,
        FUN : "sqrt"
    }, function(output){
        $("code").text(output.join("\n"));
    }); 

    //optional
    req.fail(function(){
        alert("R returned an error: " + req.responseText); 
    });
});
```